# Does using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x) slow down bots hitting site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, authentication, bots

I came across some code today that was added in the ***Logon Post Action*** of a site.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); //slow down bots
```

*(It is worth noting that the application already limits failed attempts before forcing the user to click out of the page.)*

I was wondering if sleeping the system thread was actually doing what the comment suggests, slowing down bots trying to access the site?

And is if this does slow down bots, is it effective enough that is worth having implemented?

Thanks.

Comment: is this bot hitting you in series? or in parallel? if it is making overlapping requests, it will have no effect except tying up threads on your server (which is: bad)

Comment: It slows down bots. And it pisses off users. You choose if you want to implement it.

Comment: But still it will slow down a little, because IIS doesn't fire-up new threads immediately, and there is a thread cap... So I think it will slow down bots.

Comment: @xanatos sure, but only by *not serving traffic*; that's a bit like saying "if I throttle my site for *everyone*, it will also slow down bots" - technically true, but not very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't. The reason is that login requests on the bot's side are (probably) asynchronous. After the request is sent, the bot simply releases his thread and moves on until your server responds.

On the other hand, you are locking your own thread, waiting, instead of handling other requests from legit users. You'd essentially be shooting yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.Sleep` has no place in server software, and it's use can cause ThreadPool starvation resulting in other unrelated requests become sluggish due to the lazy nature in which ThreadPool creates new threads.

If you really want to wait around doing nothing, do it asynchronously. I don't understand why this might help though. If your pagerequests are served slowly, you'll get marked down by some search engines.